# Ratio to be proved constant

Tags: geometry

OA,OB,OC are 3 given line segments and P is any point on OC. if PM and PN are the perpendiculars from P on OA and OB respectively, prove that PM:PN is a constant.

i tried proving the ratio of areas of triangle POA and POB constant. the 2 perpendiculars form a cyclic quadrilateral...but i cant get to the proof?

Comment: Hint:  The angles $\angle MPO$ and $\angle NPO$ do not depend on $P$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider another point on $OC$, $P'$, with the respective perpendiculars onto $OA$ and $OB$ being $M'$ and $N'$. Notice that $PM \parallel P'M'$ and $PN \parallel P'N'$. Thus $\triangle POM \sim \triangle P'OM'$ and $\triangle PON \sim \triangle P'ON'$

From here, we derive:

$$
\frac{PM}{PN} = \frac{P'M' \cdot \frac{OP}{OP'}}{P'N' \cdot \frac{OP}{OP'}} = \frac{P'M'}{P'N'}.
$$

Thus $\frac{PM}{PN}$ is constant for any $P$ on $OC$

Comment: But how do yu know that P dash M dash / P dash N dash is constant ?????????!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Pls reply soon... because I find difficult on proving these constant type questions....

Comment: @IMO2021GOLD the word "constant" here means that the ratio PM:PN is "independent" of the position of P on OC. So, in the solution, another Point P' is chosen and we have to prove that the ratio for point P and that for P' is same. This is done in the solution.